# fdisk Not Returning Space?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, fdisk

I'm trying to resize my ext4 partition by giving it about half of my swap space. The swap partition (/dev/sda6) currently comes right after my ext4 partition (/dev/sda5).

In `fdisk`, I remove my ext4 partition and my swap partition, but when I try to create a new partition and start it at the same spot as my old ext4 partition used to start at, fdisk won't let me, claiming that the value I entered for the first sector is out of range.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. How can I force this, or what is the proper procedure here? Do I need to do something with that Extended partition?

```
whlt@myBox:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x16d16f08

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   218609663   109303808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       218611710   250068991    15728641    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       218611712   233865215     7626752   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       233867264   250068991     8100864   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-6): 6

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-5): 5

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x16d16f08

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   218609663   109303808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       218611710   250068991    15728641    5  Extended

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 1 extended, 2 free)
   l   logical (numbered from 5)
Select (default p): l
Adding logical partition 5
First sector (218613758-250068991, default 218613758): 218611712
Value out of range.
First sector (218613758-250068991, default 218613758):
```

Comment: If you're only going to create another partition which will take up all available space, you should just get rid of the 'Extended' partition (sda2) and create a primary partition which will take up all the available space.

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear (I'll edit the question), but I'd like to keep *some* swap space, but give about half of it to the ext4 partition.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a sector that is not available to use.

```
First sector (218613758-250068991, default 218613758): 218611712
```

Change 218611712 to 218613758 ...

Not really sure why it is not.

If the sda2 the extended is empty try to delete it also and recreate it. There seems to be empty space between sda1 and sda2.

It could be that sector does not lineup to the cylinder stuff also.

Comment: Good thinking. I should have thought of that. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Good suggestion with deleting and recreating sda2, but it still gives me the same result :(  You're probably on the right track with the cylenders.